# Construct LinearSeq

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In Scala, LinearSeq and IndexedSeq are sub-traits of Seq.
If I construct a IndexedSeq, like

```
IndexedSeq(1)
```

I get the default implementation , which is Vector

```
IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1)
```

But if I try to construct a LinearSeq, as in

```
LinearSeq(1)
```

I get an error instead of the default implementation List

```
<console>:8: error: not found: value LinearSeq
          LinearSeq(1)
          ^
```

Please explain this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import it first...

```
import scala.collection.immutable.LinearSeq
```

or

```
import scala.collection.LinearSeq
```

Repl:

```
@ import scala.collection.immutable.LinearSeq 
import scala.collection.immutable.LinearSeq
@ LinearSeq(1) 
res3: LinearSeq[Int] = List(1)
```

To answer why you need to import this one but `IndexedSeq` works, see sources of `scala` package object that is imported by default:

```
type IndexedSeq[+A] = scala.collection.IndexedSeq[A]
val IndexedSeq = scala.collection.IndexedSeq
```

so designers of language brought `IndexedSeq` to default scope, they did the same for `Traversable`, `Iterable`, `Seq`, `List` and couple other things for convenience, but they didn't do that for `LinearSeq` which is probably reasonable as I never used it explicitly in my code while I used most of other things that are there.

Comment: Thank you very much. Clearly explained